# Error during SonarQube scanner execution, Unsupported Java version for PMD:

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, pmd, sonarscanner

I am unable to execute sonar analysis for PMD. I have installed a plugin for pmd (sonar-pmd-plugin-3.2.1.jar) manually and restarted the sonarqube. triggered jenkins build for the pmd analysis where it throw the error, `unsupported java version for pmd`. Please find snippet for reference.

[image: Jenkins build failed for PMD analysis in sonarqube]

Here are details for the plugins I have used:

SonarQube  : 7.1
Jenkins    : 2.164
PMD plugin : sonar-pmd-plugin-3.2.1.jar (manually placed under extensions folder in SonarQube)
Java Plugin: sonar-java-plugin-5.2.0.13398.jar (under extensions folder in SonarQube)
Sonar scanner: sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873-linux
JDK : 1.8

Work around:

- Have tried adding below both entries in sonar-scanner.properties file.

  ```
  sonar.java.source=1.8
  sonar.java.source=8
  ```
- Have changed multiple plugins for PMD and JAVA under SonarQube, here are the reference of plugin versions:

  [image: tried java plugins]

  [image: tried PMD plugins]

I have attached the Jenkins build logs.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Attaching screenshots of text instead typing (or pasting) the same text into the questions may seem to be a nice shortcut but it also means that your question is harder to find via web search.

Comment: @AttilaCsipak: it also causes problems with clipboards and screen-readers.

Comment: The exception message comes from here: https://github.com/jensgerdes/sonar-pmd/blob/94bf6862f8d216979ea38a74bda70365e31862b5/sonar-pmd-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/pmd/PmdTemplate.java#L83

It should display the version, that is not supported - but the screenshot doesn't show anything. This suggests a problem in the configuration - `sonar.java.source` is set to a empty string or not set at all....

See also https://github.com/jensgerdes/sonar-pmd

Comment: Add information how you execute the analysis, please.

Comment: That plugin is shipping a dated version of PMD (6.10.0 vs 6.22.0), over a year old. It doesn't support Java 12 and later. However, Java 8 should be supported. Please check that Maven is actually compiling the sources for target 1.8 by adding the properties `<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>` and `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>`